# How to use bootstrap button with click events in asp.net server side

Tags: asp.net

How to use bootstrap button in aspx and click event in server side. 
i have button like :

**example.aspx:**

```
    <button class="btn btn-orange btn-lg" runat="server" onclick="btnclick_click"><b><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> LOGOUT</b></button>
```

this is the button that i taken aspx file with bootstrap button with onclick event :

**example.aspx.cs :**

here i am accessing button onclick event but its not triggering

```
protected void btnclick_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First way

You can use an **asp.net button** to trigger that as

```
<asp:Button id="btnLogout"  runat="server" Text="  LOGOUT  " OnClick="btnclick_click" CssClass="fa fa-sign-out"></asp:Button>
```

To have the bootstrap theme you just set your CssClass

### Second way

You keep your code as it but because you make it run on server and its an [html button control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick(v=vs.110).aspx) you MUST use the  `onserverclick` to make it call your code behind function, and your code will be:

```
<button class="btn btn-orange btn-lg" runat="server" 
    onserverclick="btnclick_click"><b><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> LOGOUT</b></button>
```

Comment: But what about bootstrap class of button i used , and not getting correct alignment . i have used row and i am placing button inside  <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: left">

Comment: @chetu I have update my answer - just use the `onserverclick` and you done

Comment: and also not getting that fa- sign-out icon in button .. there is no way to handle bootstrap button directly in server side in asp.net

Comment: @chetu yes there is, change the `onclick` to `onserverclick` and you done... see my updated answer

Comment: onserverclick can i use this directly on bootstrap button ?

Comment: @chetu Yes - I have tested

Comment: @chetu Please vote and accept to help others show them that its works

Comment: suppose i used like :   <input id="form_land" type="tel" name="Landline" class="form-control"
                                                   placeholder="Please enter your Landline"> how to read this field user input at server side ?

Comment: @chetu You use the `name` on control and the `form` on code behind See this anser -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793212/using-classic-asp-code-inside-asp-net/20793383#20793383

Comment: @chetu In your example will be `Request.Form["Landline"]` on code behind - this will return the input

Comment: @chetu I realize this is an old post but wanted to mention the class "fa fa-sign-out" is from https://fontawesome.com

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ModalDummy" runat="server" />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalDummy_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="ModalDummy_ModalPopupExtender" TargetControlID="ModalDummy" PopupControlID="PanelPopup">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="PanelPopup" runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonContactSend">
    your popup
</asp:Panel>


ModalDummy_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.